# How can I extract data from a netCDF file for a specific location by python?

Tags: python, csv, netcat

I would like to extract climate data in specific location in Python language. But there are some issues that I could not solve it. I hope someone could help me and the code is attached below.
'''

```
f = netCDF4.Dataset('/users/james/Downloads/_data1/test2.nc')

# Extract variable
t2m = f.variables['u10']
LG = [1.18,1.18]
LT = [50.45,50.34]

# Get dimensions assuming 3D: time, latitude, longitude
time_dim, lat_dim, lon_dim = t2m.get_dims()
time_var = f.variables[time_dim.name]
times = num2date(time_var[:], time_var.units)
latitudes = f.variables[lat_dim.name][:]
longitudes = f.variables[lon_dim.name][:]

idx_lat=(latitudes>=50.34)*(latitudes<=50.45)
idx_lon=(longitudes>=1.18)*(longitudes<=1.18)
latitude=latitudes[idx_lat]
longitude=longitudes[idx_lon]


filename = os.path.join(spt_root, 'table.csv')
print(f'Writing data in tabular form to {filename} (this may take some time)...')
times_grid, latitudes_grid, longitudes_grid = [
    x.flatten() for x in np.meshgrid(times, latitude, longitude, indexing='ij')]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [t.isoformat() for t in times_grid],
    'latitude': latitudes_grid,
    'longitude': longitudes_grid,
    't2m': t2m[:].flatten()})
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
print('Done')
```

'''
The problem is shown: "arrays must all be same length"

Thank you for your help and support.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using netCDF4, you could do this in a few lines with my nctoolkit package.

```
import nctoolkit as nc
import pandas as pd
ds = nc.open_data('/users/james/Downloads/_data1/test2.nc')

# Extract variable
ds.select(variables = "u10")
# regrid to the location
LG = [1.18,1.18]
LT = [50.45,50.34]
location = pd.DataFrame({"lon":LG, "lat":LT})
ds.regrid(location, method = "nn")
# export to dataframe and then to csv
df = ds.to_dataframe().reset_index()
df.to_csv("outfile.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it but it doesn't work, shown :"NetCDF: Attribute not found".

Comment: That suggests the file is not compliant with cf or other compliance standards. This might be the cause of the original problem. Can you share the data?

Comment: Sure, could I send it to you by email?

Comment: contact details here: https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/info.html

Comment: Ok, I have sent to you, cheers!